# Can the other player put Draw 2 if your Draw 2 was the last card?

Tags: uno

Imagine a scenario where there are only two players. One of the players has only one card left, which is **Draw 2** card.

If he/she puts the card in the field, can the other player counter act with a Draw 2, or is the game over?

Comment: Playing a draw 2 in response to a draw 2 is a house rule, so this situation is by necessity handled as a house rule as well.

Answer (score 1):

**The game is over.**

After the first player plays their Draw 2, their turn is over. If their turn ends and they have no cards, they win the game. There is no opportunity for a counter-play in this situation.